# Can we use Karate's Match function inside a Javascript file?

Tags: karate

I am trying to write a generic JS Function in Karate which will pull the results from Database and store it in Json object and compare it with external json file. External File also contains Fuzzy matches such as '#null' or '#notnull' for comparision.

I want to compare these 2 objects in JS Function itself instead of passing the object to the called karate script. However the Fuzzy match strings are not being evaluated when I try to compare it in JS function.(It works when I return the Json object to karate and use 'match' function of karate).

Is there any way in which I can call Karate's Match function inside JS File?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a good idea and I've opened a feature request: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/378

Meanwhile, if you move the match operation into a separate feature, something like this:

```
Feature:
Scenario:
* def passed = false
* match actual == expected
* def passed = true
```

And call it like this:

```
var result = karate.call('match.feature', { actual: { foo: 'bar' }, expected: { foo: '#string' } })
if (!result.passed) {
  // failed
}
```

It might work ! You get the idea. Not sure if you need to catch an exception around the first line of JS above, but you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for raising a feature request Peter..:) Greatly appreciated if it could be done sometime in future. Yes I have currently used similar approach to which you have mentioned to match in common Karate script instead of JS function.

Comment: @NaveenChandra you can see it is fixed in the develop branch already, so if you can build from source you can try now. or I should be able to release a 0.8.0.RC2 in a couple of days.

Comment: I verified the karate.match function with 0.8.0.RC2 and its working as expected. Thanks :)